# How to get the variable inside

Tags: php

looking at the code: how get the variable in a function called above it

```
// section one
CTitle();
//section two
$title = 'Ben';

// section three
function CTitle(){
   global $title;
    echo 'I am: '.$title;
}
```

How do we just make it work: the order must be maintained, do not push the variable up.

Comment: place your `CTitle();` at the end of your code

Comment: It looks like you're calling the function CTitle() before setting $title?  Can you refactor your function and pass in the parameter $title?

Comment: The *real* question here is: *Why* does the order have to be maintained? What's so special about this?

Comment: the order is important, do not push the variable up, do not push the CTitle(); down either

Comment: You're not answering the question.

Comment: And what about vote to close; is that a *do* or *do not*?

Comment: good question Fred, the order should be maintained because see: 

<title> <?php CTitle();?></title>
</head>
 

<body>
function CTitle(){
// the title must come from inside the page
}
// you see, and the <title> must be in between the head tag for real

Comment: you can use sessions here, but there'd be additions made to your code

Comment: personally, I'd use sessions and it's not going to take up resources enough to crash something. what do you think sessions were made for, kids??

Comment: something new is coming to my mind: ONE CAN REFRESH A TITLE TAG WITHOUT REFRESHING THE PAGE; Aha, that is what the blokes in Gmail do with new notifications

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use sessions here while still maintaining the order (with a few additions), if that's an option you wish to use and can be used throughout multiple pages, which seems to be the case here after seeing what you wrote in comments:

```
<?php 

session_start();

// section one
CTitle();

//section two
$title = 'Ben';

$_SESSION['var'] = $title;

// section three
function CTitle(){
   global $title;

    $title = $_SESSION['var'] ;

    echo 'I am: '.$title;
}
```

Comment being:

> *"good question Fred, the order should be maintained because see:     function CTitle(){ // the title must come from inside the page } // you see, and the  must be in between the head tag for real – Ekumahost"*

and checking if the session is set throughout them all.

I.e.:

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['var'])){
// do something
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

As per [my original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578665/how-to-get-the-variable-inside#comment60756407_36578665), place your `CTitle();` at the end of your code:

```
// section one

//section two
$title = 'Ben';

// section three
function CTitle(){
   global $title;
    echo 'I am: '.$title;
}

CTitle();
```

Comment: please, we dont want to use session here... Session will consume server resources

Comment: @Ekumahost oh? how so?

Comment: downvoter, if you have something to share, do. This is a solution.

Comment: @Ekumahost Wow, haha. To be honest I'm starting to feel like this is a troll question.

Comment: Plus, why was this downvoted if it's not correct while the other answer isn't what the OP wants to use? Thanks for leaving me baffled.

Comment: anyway, whatever. The answer stays, dv or not.

Comment: @Patrick Gregorio, go take a look around. Focus on solving problems not searching for trolls. you can also hug a three phase transformer after your lunch

Comment: Don't worry about down-votes Freddy boy. SO is full of trigger happy folks

Comment: @HankyPanky No biggie. I'm not afraid of the bid bad wolf when I downvote *wrong* answers. And I fail to see how mine is *wrong*. But again...whatever. If the person can't comment, then maybe they're afraid I'll go nuts or something *lol*. Everyone's entitled to their opinion, which I might add was "left out" to back up their dv. *Cheers*

Comment: I hope you know i'm not the one who down-voted your answer (never did btw) but why do you think this session version will work? It won't. That is again reading the variable *before* giving it any value. This will work only if this session value was already set by another http request

Comment: yes, truly, this session thing will not work, after setting the session, you want me to refresh the page. lol. that also means pushing the variable up still.

Answer (score 4):

> How do we just make it work: the order must be maintained, do not push the variable up

We can't. Your variable is being initialized ***after*** you read its value. There is no escape from that goofy requirement. You can't make it work.

Defining a function before or after you call it does not make a difference in PHP, however asking that function to return uninitialized values like you expect is like asking it to read your mind.

**However**

You can take some help from OOP, since this does not fall under your strict **do not** policy

```
<?php

$test=new CTitle();

class CTitle{
 public static $title = 'Ben';
 public function CTitle(){
    echo 'I am: '.self::$title;
 }
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/552299)**

Comment: [*Or...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578665/how-to-get-the-variable-inside#comment60756407_36578665)

Comment: Yeah that's true but the OP said *do not push the variable up* which blocks that route

Comment: Like you said: *can't be done* ;-) no idea why they can't change that.

Comment: Could also use sessions.

Comment: OP might need more lessons in web development, after that I am willing to bet my lunch for today that he can change the order.

Comment: No hanky, you collected your $title from the class, which is not the idea, bring it outside thus: <?php

$test=new CTitle();
 public static $title = 'Ben';
class CTitle{

 public function CTitle(){
    echo 'I am: '.self::$title;
 }
}

Comment: ^ which is what I said from the get go

Answer (score 0):

In the context of an HTML structure like your comment earlier:

> No hanky, you collected your $title from the class, which is not the
>   idea, bring it outside thus: $test=new CTitle(); public static
>   $title = 'Ben'; class CTitle{ public function CTitle(){ echo 'I am:
>   '.self::$title; } }

```
<?php
$title = 'Ben';

function CTitle(){
    global $title;
    echo 'I am: '.$title;
}
?>
<html>
    <head><title><?php CTitle(); ?></title></head>
    <body>
        <?php CTitle(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no different than what [my original comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578665/how-to-get-the-variable-inside#comment60756407_36578665) said and added to my answer afterwards, where I might add the OP accepted (so far). All you did was take their code and incorporated it in there.